# jquery plugin pass value by function return

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a simple jquery plugin. It is working fine when i pass a value. But not working when a function returns a value. It's shows the function defenition.

Please try this in [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ykGGs/1/)

```
(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.greenify = function( options ) {

        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            color: "#556b2f",
            backgroundColor: "white",
            selectedID:function(){}    
        }, options );

        alert(settings.selectedID);
    };
}( jQuery ));


//Plugin Call
$( "div" ).greenify({
    color: "orange",
    //selectedID:6  it is working fine
    selectedID:function (){return 5}
});
```

Comment: You're not executing the function, just passing a function object.

Comment: _Why_ are you wanting to pass a function there? Why is the default value specified for `selectedID` a function? The name "selectedID" implies that it will be an ID (number or string), not a function, so if you want to use a function when you call `.greenify()` you'd need to call your function yourself and pass the return. If the `.greenify()` plugin is expecting `selectedID` to be a function then the plugin code would need to treat it as such and call it by adding parentheses (`alert(settings.selectedID())`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing a function reference to `alert()` when you call `alert(settings.selectedID)`, instead you need to invoke the function referred by `settings.selectedID` and pass the value returned by it to `alert()`

So try

```
alert(settings.selectedID());
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5arKu/)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `"()"` here

```
alert(settings.selectedID);
```

So ideally you have to invoke the function to work it properly

```
alert(settings.selectedID());
```

Answer (score 0):

settings.selectedID is a function

```
alert(settings.selectedID());
```